# Refactoring asynchronous CoffeeScript doing AJAX

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, methods, coffeescript, refactoring

The code below is working, but I'm not quite satisfied concerning the responsibility of the methods. I tried to keep the methods shallow and "single responsibility" but they still do too much different things IMO.

In a synchronous world I would have three methods:

- doajax(url) that returns the response
- parse(response) that returns the array of data
- draw(data) that creates the graph with the array

But I don't know how to do this in this asynchronous case. Any clues how to reorganize? There will be several graphs and I want to be able to update a given graph with new data without creating a new one, so there will be a method like updateGraph(graphId, newData)

```
doajax = (url) ->
  $.ajax
    url: url
    dataType: 'html'
    success: (response) ->
      parse response

parse = (response) ->
  xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response)
  xml = $(xmlDoc)
  arr = []
  xml.find('S').each ->
    timestamp = new Date($(this).attr('T'))
    value = parseFloat($(this).attr('AI1'))
    arr.push [timestamp, value]
  draw arr

draw = (data) ->
  new Dygraph($('#graph1')[0], data,
  // options..
  )

doajax 'http://api.example.com/stats.xml'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dynamic callbacks, instead of calling the other predefined functions:

```
doajax 'http://api.example.com/stats.xml', (xml) -> draw(parse(xml))
```

Or simply use the [deferred/promise object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) returned by [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), which you indeed can immediately return:

```
doajax = (url) ->
  $.ajax
    url: url
    dataType: 'xml' # or use 'text' for explicitly calling jQuery.parseXML

parse = (xmlDoc) ->
  $(xmlDoc).find('S').map ->
    timestamp = new Date($(this).attr('T'))
    value = parseFloat($(this).attr('AI1'))
    [timestamp, value]
  .toArray()

draw = (data) ->
  new Dygraph($('#graph1')[0], data,
  # options..
  )

doajax 'http://api.example.com/stats.xml'
  .then parse
  .then draw
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. I have read about deferred/promise but couldn't apply it to my code since I'm quite novice to JS. Thanks Bergi!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery, there's a powerful feature called promises through for instance `jQuery.Deferred` which is also built into jQuery.ajax

So what you could do is:

```
doajax = (url) ->
  $.ajax
    url: url
    dataType: 'xml'

parse = (response) ->
  xml = $(response)
  arr = []
  xml.find('S').each ->
    timestamp = new Date($(this).attr('T'))
    value = parseFloat($(this).attr('AI1'))
    arr.push [timestamp, value]
  draw arr

draw = (data) ->
  new Dygraph($('#graph1')[0], data,
  // options..
)
```

And call it by chaining the functions like so:

```
doajax("/blabla")
    .then(parse)
    .then(draw)
```

The return value from each function will be passed in as an argument into the next one.